# JS/Jquery - Recording Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a webpage, basically, I want a button to be able to capture the webpage until the capture is stopped, then output as an avi or similar.

I've looked around and couldn't see a way to do this. Is it even possible?

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: never seen any feature like that. could be possible through Java.

Comment: @Mustaghees, any chance you could create something for me then? I've no idea how I would do this, as I would like in inbuilt into the webpage with just a start, stop webpage capture button.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to do it?